# How can I set a default value on router.back() for deep linked items in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have two (or more) VueJS routes that contain a router-link pointing to the same third route.

/pages/list

```
<router-link :to="{name:'add-page'}">Add</router-link>
```

/pages/other-list

```
<router-link :to="{name:'add-page'}">Add</router-link>
```

If I put a put link on the third page with `$router.back()`, the link will take me back in history to whichever previous page I came from.

However, if enter the `add-page` route directly into my browser, there is no history. I would like to set a default value for that page, and preferably not rely on a global default.

What is the best way to select a default route if there is no history on a specific component?

Answer (score 0):

Would a **[Navigation Guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)** fits your needs?

You would use it something like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    if (to.name === 'add-page' && to.) {

         //Your logic here
         //eg a redirect
         next({ name: 'MyBaseRoute' }) 

     } else {
        next()
     }    
})
```

or if you need just for a selected component you can use the **[in-component guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)**:

> ```
>   beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
>     // called before the route that renders this component is confirmed.
>     // does NOT have access to `this` component instance,
>     // because it has not been created yet when this guard is called!
>   },
> ```